# UISwipeGestureRecognizer method not called?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

In my Box2d game i try to use uiswipegesture to get the swipe gesture up and when i do in test project it works fine but when i implement in box2d game it does not called swipe action here is the code

```
{UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureup = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(oneFingerSwipeUp)];
    [swipeGestureup setDirection: UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp ];



    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureup];

    [swipeGestureup release];}
```

and method is

```
-(void)oneFingerSwipeUp:(id)sender{

NSLog(@"swipe auction called");

[player jump];
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
  UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureup = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(oneFingerSwipeUp:)];
  [swipeGestureup setDirection: UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp ];

  [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureup];

  [swipeGestureup release];
 }

- (void)oneFingerSwipeUp:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
  NSLog(@"swipe auction called");

  }
```

Comment: Care to explain the changes you made?

Comment: add recognizer in method oneFingerSwipeUp .. `(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer`

Comment: That is not the problem (but incidentally there is another difference between your code and OP's that DOES fix the problem)

Comment: Yes, that is a crucial difference

Comment: itry the solution of @RinjuJain but its not wrking